# database in not working in flutter desktop (windows)

Tags: database, flutter, local-storage, floor, flutter-desktop

Want to store local data in flutter desktop application, I have used floor database for my mobile application.
It is working fine when we run in debug mode but when we make release build it does not work.

Or please guide if there is another way to achieve local storage functionality.

Please help me to solve my local storage issue for desktop application.
Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 1):

I think the root cause is, in debug mode, sqlite3.dll is bundled.
However, in release mode, you have to add sqlite3.dll in same folder as your executable manually.

See this:
https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite_common_ffi
You may find the sqlite3.dll download link in the page.